# How to read text file on python and get values from it to set it on an array

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

I have a text file which have the following structure:

< example_name>TAB< probability >TAB< prediction>

This an example of this file:

> Q1_R1 0.00390625  true
>
> Q1_R2 0.0078125   false
>
> Q1_R3 0.001953125 false
>
> Q1_R4 0.125   true

I'm using the environment Anaconda2 (Python Version 2.7) especially the scikit-learn tools, and my question is:
How can i load this text file and put the values of the element < probability> on an array to do other operations ?

Comment: Yes, you can . What have you tried?

Comment: @Brian I'm a debutant, and  i don't know how to do that !!

Comment: Is there a problem in simply go through each line of the file splitting by spaces and get the second element of the splitted line?

Comment: @RodrigoM.Racanicci thank you for the answer, this what i want, how can i do it ?

Comment: I believe @Brian did what you want in the answer just below! ;) 
You could even map it to a _float_ if you wish `float(line.split()[1])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, make an attempt before you ask a question. In Python, the way I would do that would be to use a **list comprehension** when reading the file

```
probs = [line.split()[1] for line in open('filename','r')]
```

Comment: Thank you @Brian this is exactly what i want to do, i really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome, but next time you post on SO, make sure you show your attempt first!!

Comment: there exist lot of documentation about that for that i can't make an attempt